# Manipulation of Variables with Similar Names in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I was wondering if there was a more terse way of manipulating variables (in my context dividing) variables that have near identical names.

Please consider the following dataset:

```
library(data.table)
n = 100
DT <- data.table(id = seq(1, n),
                 A1 = rnorm(n), A2 = rnorm(n), A3 = rnorm(n),
                 B1 = rnorm(n), B2 = rnorm(n), B3 = rnorm(n),
                 C1 = rnorm(n), C2 = rnorm(n), C3 = rnorm(n))
```

Here, there are 9 variables with the following pattern: There are string identifiers (the "A", "B", "C") and there are number identifiers (1,2,3). I would like to create variables that divide the various variables *within* the string identifiers like the following (if I were to do it manually):

```
DT[, `:=`(A_1_2 = A1/A2, A_1_3 = A1/A3, A_2_3 = A2/A3,
          B_1_2 = B1/B2, B_1_3 = B1/B3, B_2_3 = B2/B3,
          C_1_2 = C1/C2, C_1_3 = C1/C3, C_2_3 = C2/C3)]
```

Of course, with a smaller dataset, a manual approach is simple and easy. The problem is that the data is large in both the length of unique string and integer identifiers.

Comment: Change `id = rep(1, n)` to `id = seq(1, n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
for(nm in LETTERS[1:3]) {

   DT[, paste(nm, 1, c(2,3), sep="_") := .(.SD[[1]]/.SD[[2]], 
              .SD[[1]]/.SD[[3]]), .SDcols = patterns(nm)]
}
```

-output

```
> head(DT)
      id         A1         A2         A3         B1         B2         B3         C1         C2         C3      A_1_2      A_1_3      B_1_2      B_1_3
   <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>
1:     1  0.3542970  0.6165800 -0.1864986 -0.5327489  0.4524059 -1.0155552  0.4424219  1.0036830 -0.7000798  0.5746165 -1.8997306 -1.1775905  0.5245888
2:     1  0.3636432  0.5636047  0.2285641 -1.1874976  0.5418400  0.2764359  1.6741682  0.3488773  3.1991003  0.6452096  1.5909900 -2.1916020 -4.2957426
3:     1 -1.0641223  1.0731815  1.3408351  1.3454667  0.0338082 -1.2930563 -1.7898783  1.5873107  0.4569702 -0.9915585 -0.7936265 39.7970564 -1.0405322
4:     1  0.6483625 -0.3086274 -0.6715842 -1.0044038 -0.2900828  1.9253284  1.2584133 -0.3501206  0.4703024 -2.1007937 -0.9654225  3.4624735 -0.5216792
5:     1  0.6551013  1.2308940 -0.7867075  0.5416599 -0.8100544  0.5734997  0.6046887  0.5044593 -0.9537713  0.5322159 -0.8327127 -0.6686711  0.9444817
6:     1 -0.2912931 -1.7403816  0.8714699 -0.2484992 -1.7435360 -0.5650502  0.3410640  0.8594608 -0.4863061  0.1673731 -0.3342549  0.1425260  0.4397825
        C_1_2      C_1_3
        <num>      <num>
1:  0.4407985 -0.6319592
2:  4.7987299  0.5233247
3: -1.1276168 -3.9168383
4: -3.5942282  2.6757535
5:  1.1986868 -0.6339976
6:  0.3968349 -0.7013361
```

---

Or may also use `split.default`

```
DT1 <-  cbind(DT, DT[, lapply(split.default(.SD, sub("\\d+", "", 
    names(.SD))), \(x) replicate(2, x[[1]], 
    simplify = FALSE)/x[,-1, with = FALSE]), .SDcols = -1])
```

#### Update

If we need all the combinations

```
tmp <- DT[, lapply(split.default(.SD, sub("\\d+", "", names(.SD))), 
     function(x) {x1 <- combn(x, 2, 
     FUN = function(y) y[[1]]/y[[2]])
      nm1 <- combn(names(x), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "_")
      setNames(as.data.frame(x1), nm1)
      }),  .SDcols = -1]
names(tmp) <- sub("^[^.]+\\.", "", names(tmp))
DT1 <- cbind(DT, tmp)
```

-output

```
> head(DT1, 3)
      id         A1        A2         A3         B1        B2         B3         C1        C2         C3      A1_A2      A1_A3      A2_A3     B1_B2
   <num>      <num>     <num>      <num>      <num>     <num>      <num>      <num>     <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>     <num>
1:     1  0.3542970 0.6165800 -0.1864986 -0.5327489 0.4524059 -1.0155552  0.4424219 1.0036830 -0.7000798  0.5746165 -1.8997306 -3.3060843 -1.177591
2:     1  0.3636432 0.5636047  0.2285641 -1.1874976 0.5418400  0.2764359  1.6741682 0.3488773  3.1991003  0.6452096  1.5909900  2.4658500 -2.191602
3:     1 -1.0641223 1.0731815  1.3408351  1.3454667 0.0338082 -1.2930563 -1.7898783 1.5873107  0.4569702 -0.9915585 -0.7936265  0.8003829 39.797056
        B1_B3       B2_B3      C1_C2      C1_C3      C2_C3
        <num>       <num>      <num>      <num>      <num>
1:  0.5245888 -0.44547643  0.4407985 -0.6319592 -1.4336693
2: -4.2957426  1.96009249  4.7987299  0.5233247  0.1090548
3: -1.0405322 -0.02614596 -1.1276168 -3.9168383  3.4735543
```

Comment: @plausibly_exogenous is there any issue in the solution?

Comment: I just realized that I forgot to ask in my post that I also need 2_3 for each variable. So not just 1_2 and 1_3 but also 2_3. Also, if there were 4 numbers. It would need 1_2, 2_3, 3_4, 2_3,2_4, etc. So all “upward” cases. Thank you. This was my fault for not communicating this.

Comment: Hi @akrun, your latest solution seems to work. But the only issue with this one is that the variable names come out to be A.V1, A.V2, and it isn't clear how these names map to what is being divided. The names are important in cases where the number of combinations are very large. Thank you so much.

Comment: @plausibly_exogenous try the update